# Changed width/height when changing size of screen

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, screen-orientation

I want to change width & height(scale) all grid,images,text automatically...when changing size a screens.
Higher screens then text or images are smaller...change in my app for different Screen Resolution and Screen size.

Answer (score 0):

The `SharedSizeGroup` attribute when defining `ColumnDefinition` could be of some help here assuming you're using `Grids`. An MSDN article about it could be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751905.aspx.
Alternatively, you could create some sort of cascading bindings using the likes of this:    `<TextBox Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeOtherControl, Path=ActualHeight}" />`